# CakePHP4 Cookbookの「Articles の検証ルールの更新」で "Declaration of ~ must be compatible with ~"エラー

Tags: php, cakephp

いまCakePHP4 CookbookのCMSチュートリアルを試しています。
CakeはPHPバージョン7.3.xのサーバーでホストしています。

CakePHP4 Cookbook　「[Articles の検証ルールの更新](https://book.cakephp.org/4/ja/tutorials-and-examples/cms/articles-controller.html#articles)」の箇所で指示通り

```
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
```

の読み込みと、

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->allowEmptyString('title', false)
        ->minLength('title', 10)
        ->maxLength('title', 255)

        ->allowEmptyString('body', false)
        ->minLength('body', 10);

    return $validator;
}
```

のメソッド追加をして

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
//Textクラス
use Cake\Utility\Text;

use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config) : void
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }

    public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options)
    {
        if ($entity->isNew() && !$entity->slug) {
            $sluggedTitle = Text::slug($entity->title);
            //スラグをスキーマで定義されている最大長に調整
            $entity->slug = substr($sluggedTitle, 0, 191);
        }
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('title', false)
            ->minLength('title', 10)
            ->maxLength('title', 255)

            ->allowEmptyString('body', false)
            ->minLength('body', 10);

        return $validator;
    }

}
```

というコードにして/articles/をリロードしたところ、

```
Fatal error: Declaration of App\Model\Table\ArticlesTable::validationDefault(Cake\Validation\Validator $validator) must be compatible with Cake\ORM\Table::validationDefault(Cake\Validation\Validator $validator): Cake\Validation\Validator in /home/***/++++.com/public_html/cms/src/Model/Table/ArticlesTable.php on line 10
```

というエラーが出てしまい、回避できずに困っております。
どなたかこちらのエラー回避方法をご存知ありませんか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fatal error: Declaration ~` は親クラスのメソッドと引数、戻り値の型定義が異なる場合に出るエラーです。

親クラスの `Cake\ORM\Table::validationDefault` は、

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
```

となっていますので同様に戻り値の型指定 `: Validator` を入れてください。

---

そもそもドキュメントのソースコードが3.xのままの記述だったので、間違いの元でしたね。

該当ページで、英語版のソースコードとの差分は以下になります。

https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/6651/files

修正リクエストは投げましたので、そのうち反映されるはずです。

Comment: ご教示いただきありがとうございます。ja版とen版で記述が違うことなども予め考慮しておくべきでした。”:Validator”を追記したところ、問題なく動作いたしました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: CakePHPのコミュでも同様の指摘を受けましたが、向こうの方はそもそもen版しか見ていないらしく、ただ記述抜かしてるよとだけ言われてしまいましたw

Answer (score 0):

すいません。私の記述ミスでした。

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) : Validator
```

としなければならないところ、

```
: Validator
```

を抜かして書いておりました。私の見落としでした。

Comment: そもそもドキュメントが間違っていたので、この質問により修正できました。指摘ありがとうございました。